# sort() Multidimensional Arrays with change value before

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want sorting multidimensional array. But I must to change format value to sorting before then get back format in beginning.

**This my array (multidimensional)**

```
$db = [['1','00:01:13.145'], ['2','00:02:19.145'],
       ['3','00:02:13.235'], ['4','00:01:44.020'], 
       ['5','00:02:25.035'], ['6','00:01:11.031']];
```

For example can help you to answer, I Know a part how to sorting array time and to get format back again:

**This my array (single)**

```
$db2 = ['00:01:13.145','00:02:19.145',
        '00:02:13.235','00:01:44.020', 
        '00:02:25.035','00:01:11.031'];
```

**Function to sorting this**

```
$rep = str_replace(':','', str_replace('.','', $db2));
echo arr($rep);

function arr($array) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $return[] = (int)$row;
        sort($return);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**The output will be**

Array ( [0] => 111031 [1] => 113145 [2] => 144020 [3] => 213235 [4] => 219145 [5] => 225035 )

**Second, I know how to get format again, example:**

```
$int = 111031;
$str = substr_replace(substr_replace($int,".",-3,-3),":",-6,-6);
echo substr_replace($str,'00:0',-9,-9);
```

**from** `(int)111031` **the output will be** `00:01:11.031`

Pleas help me to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here we simply use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to use our own custom compare function. In this function we first [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the time by a dot, so we get the time and the milliseconds separately. After this we convert the time into a timestamp with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and multiply it by 1,000 so we can add the milliseconds to it.

With this we have converted the time into milliseconds and we can simply compare the numbers and sort by the milliseconds.

Code:

```
<?php

    $db = [
              ['1','00:01:13.145'], ['2','00:02:19.145'],
              ['3','00:02:13.235'], ['4','00:01:44.020'], 
              ['5','00:02:25.035'], ['6','00:01:11.031']
          ];


    usort($db, function($a, $b){
        list($timeOne, $millisecondsOne) = explode(".", $a[1]);
        list($timeTwo, $millisecondsTwo) = explode(".", $b[1]);

        $millisecondsOne = strtotime($timeOne) * 1000 + $millisecondsOne;
        $millisecondsTwo = strtotime($timeTwo) * 1000 + $millisecondsTwo;

        if($millisecondsOne == $millisecondsTwo)
            return 0;
        return $millisecondsOne > $millisecondsTwo ? 1 : -1;

   });

    print_r($db);

?>
```

Comment: wow thank your answer it's so simple and great. And my example it's so complicated ahahahha sorry :D